# pyarrow timestamp datatype error on parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

I have this error when I read and count records in pandas using pyarrow, I do not want pyarrow to convert to timestamp[ns], it can keep in timestamp[us], is there an option to keep timestamp as is  ?, i am using pyarrow 11.0,0 and python 3.10.Please advise

code:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pyarrow.compute as pc
import pandas as pd

# Read the Parquet file into a PyArrow Table
table = pq.read_table('/Users/abc/Downloads/LOAD.parquet').to_pandas()

print(len(table))
```

error

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[us] to timestamp[ns] would result in out of bounds timestamp: 101999952000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want pyarrow to convert to timestamp[ns], it can keep in timestamp[us], is there an option to keep timestamp as is ?

At the moment, `pandas` only support nanosecond timestamp.

If you insist on keeping us precision you have a few options:

1. not use pandas, stick to pyarrow which supports microseconds:

```py
table = pq.read_table("data.parquet")
len(table)
```

2. Use datetime.datetime instead of pd.Timestamp in your dataframe (very slow)

```py
table = pq.read_table("data.parquet")
df = table.to_pandas(timestamp_as_object=True)
```

3. Ignore the loss of precision for the timestamps that are out of range

```
table = pq.read_table("data.parquet")
df = table.to_pandas(safe=False)
```

But the original timestamp that was `5202-04-02` becomes `1694-12-04`

4. If you're feeling intrepid use pandas 2.0 and pyarrow as a backend for pandas

```bash
pip install  pandas==2.0.0rc1
```

```py
pd.read_parquet("data.parquet", dtype_backend="pyarrow")
```

5. Fix the data using pyarrow

Surely 5202-04-02 is a typo. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74467923/pandas-read-parquet-error-pyarrow-lib-arrowinvalid-casting-from-timestampus/74474108#74474108)

Comment: As of late July '23 Pandas 2.0 has been out for a while, and #4 from this answer solved this issue for me.