# parquet time stamp overflow with fastparquet/pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

I have a parquet file I am reading from s3 using fastparquet/pandas , the parquet file has a column with date 2022-10-06 00:00:00 ,  and I see it is wrapping it as  1970-01-20 06:30:14.400, Please see  code and error and screen shot of parquet file below  .I am not sure why this is happening ?
2022-09-01 00:00:00 seems to be fine.
if I choose "pyarrow" as the engine, it fails with exception

```
pyarrow error:
    pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[us] to timestamp[ns] would result in out of bounds timestamp: 101999952000000000
```

Please advise.

fastparquet error:

```
OverflowError: value too large
Exception ignored in: 'fastparquet.cencoding.time_shift'
OverflowError: value too large
OverflowError: value too large
```

code:

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket="blah", Key="blah1")
df=pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()),engine="fastparquet")
```

Comment: `2022-10-06 00:00:00 = 1661990400000000 nanos`. `1661990400000000 // 1000` as a nanos timestamp is `1970-01-20 06:30:14.400`. It looks to me like your data is mixing us and ns timestamp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyarrow timestamp datatype error on parquet file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897897/pyarrow-timestamp-datatype-error-on-parquet-file)

Comment: no this does not answer @0x26res ,  I am not sure why the above date is a problem of overflow, it is between 1677 and 2262 years per  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323548/what-determines-pandas-minimum-and-maximum-timestamp.  Any ideas why this is happening ?, If I open the parquet file in parquet viewer online, I see 2022-10-06 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

When pyarrow and fastparquet agree that the data isn't valid, I expect it must be the case. As a comment suggests, it sounds like there is confusion in the column's time units. You didn't say where the data came from, but at a wild guess, this may be because of the change in parquet standard (roughly v1->v2), in which the former complex types were extended by new "logical" types. Newer parquet files tend to have BOTH styles of type declaration, so there is a chance they are inconsistent.

In fastparquet main branch (unreleased), there was [some work](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/pull/870) to consolidate different ways of declaring time types. Maybe for your data, it now does the right thing.